# How to test code with singletons?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have an old application with code fragments like these:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void executeSomeSqlStatement()
    {
        final Connection dbConn = ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();

        final PreparedStatement statement = dbConn.prepareStatement(); // NullPointerException, if ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection() returns null
    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test, which verifies that *MyClass.executeSomeSqlStatement* doesn't throw a *NullPointerException*, when *ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection()* returns null.

How can I do it (mock *ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection()*) without changing the design of the class (without removing the singleton) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167210/different-singleton-instances-with-junit-tests This might help you.

Comment: According to your code, throwing a NPE would be the corre t thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic), which supports mocking of static methods.

Something along these lines:

```
// at the class level
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ConnectionPool.class)

// at the beginning your test method
mockStatic(ConnectionPool.class);

final ConnectionPool cp = createMock(ConnectionPool.class);
expect(cp.getConnection()).andReturn(null);
expect(ConnectionPool.getInstance()).andReturn(cp);

replay(ConnectionPool.class, cp);

// the rest of your test
```

Comment: Which version of PowerMock should I use? In 1.5.1 there is no `PowerMock.expect` method.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko They are delivred by the mock library that chose to use together with PowerMock: EasyMock or Mockito.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to use the PowerMock framework.

With it you can mock static methods. http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

This can also be very useful if your tests depend on `System.currentTimeMillis()`, because you can mock it too.